# Working with OBJ or STL files in Tensorflow/CNN

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, graphics

As part of a project, OBJ or STL files are to be processed so that they can be used as inputs to a CNN with a conv_3d input layer developed with Tensorflow. R is primarily used but Python can also be an option.

The core question is: how can a 4-dimensional array with shape (x, y, z, channel) be generated from an OBJ or STL file?

As always, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A 4-dimensional array? Isn't it rather a 2-dimensional array with 4 columns? Could you show a piece of such a file? What about the faces of the mesh, you don't want them?

Comment: Thanks! We want to use a 3D U-Net developed by us. This CNN works pretty fine with NIfTI files where the 3d arrays can directly be extracted and expanded with a further dimension to serve as inputs for a layer_conv_3d. We thought that this can also be made with an OBJ or STL file after some processing. Or am I wrong and we should work with another type of CNN?